# what is rootpath in javascript src attribute?

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm developing a .net web application. I want to link to a js file in one of my user control. I tried ./, I also tried ~, neither works. what is rootpath in src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/filename.js")"></script>
```

Depends on what .net version you're working in. This is MVC 3 Using the Razor Syntax

Comment: I have another Example from a .net project using WebForms but I believe you've already tried that as well.     <script src="Scripts/lib/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

Comment: Where are your scripts located? O_o

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop that js file in your control it will automatically link your js file to the control without any error.

Comment: You do not need to use the @username syntax when answering questions.